# Catching the redirected address from NSURLConnection

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, redirect, nsurlconnection, blocking

I'm working on a software which follows the HTTP redirection which is dynamically calculated by the server depending on a pparameter. I don't want to show the primary server in Mobile Safari but rather the redirected address only.
The following code workks:

```
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:originalUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    // Extract the redirected URL
target = [response URL];
```

The problem is that the server requires several seconds to answer. The `sendSynchronousRequest` blocks the app for this time completely which is messy, I can't even display the "Busy" animation.

Does anyone know how I can retrieve the redirected address asynchronously without safari appearance in the meanwhile with the redirecting server URL or display some sort of the "Be patient" animation during the `sendSynchronousRequest`? What disadvantages would have the passing of `sendSynchronousRequest` in another thread?

Answer (score 3):

Use the asynchronous behavior provided by `NSURLConnection` and provide the connection with a delegate which implements [-connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHIIDH)

Then go read [Five Reasons Why Synchronous Networking Is Bad](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/9606?tstart=0)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I did. After some messing around with the reference counts I got it working